# Function is not inserted into an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert a function into an array, but in turns into `null`. How could this be?

```
        this.over[name].push(typeof this[name])
        this.over[name].push(this[name])
        console.log(name, typeof this[name], JSON.stringify(this.over))
```

Result

```
        on_key function {"on_key":["function",null]}
```

Comment: Try just logging the object without stringifying it to JSON. `console.log(this.over)`. Most consoles will render it so you can see or browse each property and value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function *is* inserted into the array.

The problem is that you are trying to JSON.stringify a function and JSON doesn't have a function data type. Express whatever you want to express using the function in some other means if you want to convert it to JSON.

Comment: That isn't what [the JSON.stringify documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) says: If undefined, a function, or an XML value is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).

Comment: Calling `.toString()` on a function will show you the function body in some JavaScript implementations, JSON.stringify should not.